# What Javascript IDEs can display code hints for Three.js?

Tags: javascript, ide, editor, three.js, code-hinting

I need to find a Javascript IDE or editor that can display code hints for external files such as Three.js.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It depends on what operating system you are using and other parameters. But for a start I would recommend looking at [Sublime text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) for cross-platform, it should either figure out code-completion or perhaps there are plugins for doing so? otherwise I've found [alternative to](http://alternativeto.net/) to be a helpful place. Hope you find what you are looking for.

Comment: The Three.js project includes a Sublime Text 2 [extension](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/utils/editors/sublimetext2) that adds code hinting. I am not sure which editors do the best job of this generically (e.g. by reading arbitrary external files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer, I'm the author of the tern.java.

If you use Eclipse, I suggest you that you [install tern.java 0.10.0](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Installation-Update-Site) (not released) which provides a [tern support for three.js](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-&-Threejs-support) with completion for three.js :

[image]

If you are using other JavaScript Editors like Emacs, Vim, Sublime, you can use the tern plugin [tern-threejs](https://github.com/tylerwbell/tern-threejs)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/)

Get the  [Personal Licence](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/buy/) if it's just for yourself for personal use, you can try for 30 days.

Comment: This is better-suited as a comment.